# Questions that are pretty much on topic but the answers are maybe found elsewhere

Tags: discussion

With most Off Topic questions it is easy to comment saying where they should go within the network or elsewhere with their answer, but what about when a question is on topic but perhaps even more relevant somewhere else (and there isn't already such a question in place).

Case in point - [Math behind multivariate testing for website optimization](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22511/math-behind-multivariate-testing-for-website-optimization)

In my mind it definitely belongs as a webmaster question, but the proposed solution (which appears to have been accepted) was to ask the question on another SE website.

If this question should be closed, what should it be closed with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close > Off Topic > Belongs on... > Statistics SE

In this case, the question was already posed with [Math behind multivariate testing for website optimization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18923/math-behind-multivariate-testing-for-website-optimization) so I'm going to close as off topic rather than migrate a duplicate, but please *do* flag for migration over telling the asker to ask again wherever possible.